# Override all shipping method titles based on condition - Magento 2

Tags: checkout, shipping

We have a custom field on the checkout shipping page. If this field is selected we want to override the shipping method title. For instance if the shipping method title is "Standard shipping" we want to change it to "Standard Shipping - Extra text".

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plug-in.

< type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
<plugin name="mageworx_validate_subtotal_with_discount" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\FreeShipping"/ >
< /type >

Vendor\Module\Plugin\FreeShipping.php

public function aroundGetConfigData(OriginalFreeShipping $subject, callable $proceed, $field)
{
$value = $proceed($field);

```
    if ($field != 'free_shipping_subtotal') {
        return $value;
    }

    //configure the code to map shipping with order status (field)

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $baseDiscount = $shippingAddress->getBaseDiscountAmount();
    $value += abs($baseDiscount);

    return $value;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I was looking to override the title for all shipping methods.